# Set the image duration with jcodec in android

Tags: java, android, jcodec

i am making an app that makes a video with few pictures.
my problem is that the video with 20 or 30 images have a 1 second duration.
I create the encoder in my `OnCreate` method and in a Timer, i use this

```
 encoder.encodeNativeFrame(pic);
```

The Timer run each second.

And when i press a finish button, i add this code

```
 encoder.finish();
```

But when i view the video, i view all images in one second.

Can i set the duration? For example, add one image every second?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to use fram animation to do this

Comment: No, i dont need animation

Answer (score 1):

You have to just call like

```
SequenceEncoder encoder = new SequenceEncoder(Outputfile, Constants.VIDEO_WIDTH, Constants.VIDEO_HEIGHT, durationInSeconds);
```

It works for me.

Comment: added compile 'org.jcodec:jcodec-android:0.1.9' in app build.gradle but unable to access some classes

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SequenceEncoder {
    private SeekableByteChannel ch;
    private Picture toEncode;
    private RgbToYuv420 transform;
    private H264Encoder encoder;
    private ArrayList<ByteBuffer> spsList;
    private ArrayList<ByteBuffer> ppsList;
    private FramesMP4MuxerTrack outTrack;
    private ByteBuffer _out;
    private int frameNo;
    private MP4Muxer muxer;
    public SequenceEncoder(File out) throws IOException {
        this.ch = NIOUtils.writableFileChannel(out);

        // Transform to convert between RGB and YUV
        transform = new RgbToYuv420(0, 0);

        // Muxer that will store the encoded frames
        muxer = new MP4Muxer(ch, Brand.MP4);

        // Add video track to muxer
         outTrack = muxer.addTrackForCompressed(TrackType.VIDEO, 1);

        // Allocate a buffer big enough to hold output frames
        _out = ByteBuffer.allocate(1920 * 1080 * 6);

        // Create an instance of encoder
        encoder = new H264Encoder();

        // Encoder extra data ( SPS, PPS ) to be stored in a special place of
        // MP4
        spsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
        ppsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();

    }

    public void encodeImage(Bitmap bi) throws IOException {
        // encodeNativeFrame(AWTUtil.fromBufferedImage(bi));
        encodeNativeFrame(fromBitmap(bi));
    }

    public void encodeNativeFrame(Picture pic) throws IOException {
        if (toEncode == null) {
            toEncode = Picture.create(pic.getWidth(), pic.getHeight(),
                    ColorSpace.YUV420);
        }

        // Perform conversion
        transform.transform(pic, toEncode);

        // Encode image into H.264 frame, the result is stored in '_out' buffer
        _out.clear();
        ByteBuffer result = encoder.encodeFrame(_out, toEncode);

        // Based on the frame above form correct MP4 packet
        spsList.clear();
        ppsList.clear();
        H264Utils.encodeMOVPacket(result, spsList, ppsList);

        // Add packet to video track
        outTrack.addFrame(new MP4Packet(result, frameNo, 1, 5, frameNo, true,
                null, frameNo, 0));
        frameNo++;
    }

    public void finish() throws IOException {
        // Push saved SPS/PPS to a special storage in MP4
        outTrack.addSampleEntry(H264Utils.createMOVSampleEntry(spsList, ppsList));

        // Write MP4 header and finalize recording
        muxer.writeHeader();
        NIOUtils.closeQuietly(ch);
    }

    public static Picture fromBitmap(Bitmap src) {
        Picture dst = Picture.create((int) src.getWidth(),
                (int) src.getHeight(), ColorSpace.RGB);
        fromBitmap(src, dst);
        return dst;
    }

    public static void fromBitmap(Bitmap src, Picture dst) {
        int[] dstData = dst.getPlaneData(0);
        int[] packed = new int[src.getWidth() * src.getHeight()];

        src.getPixels(packed, 0, src.getWidth(), 0, 0, src.getWidth(),
                src.getHeight());

        for (int i = 0, srcOff = 0, dstOff = 0; i < src.getHeight(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < src.getWidth(); j++, srcOff++, dstOff += 3) {
                int rgb = packed[srcOff];
                dstData[dstOff] = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;
                dstData[dstOff + 1] = (rgb >> 8) & 0xff;
                dstData[dstOff + 2] = rgb & 0xff;
            }
        }
    }

}
```